# All files become hidden in Nautilus file manager

Tags: command-line, nautilus

When I `cd` to a directory via Terminal and when I create a file every time via terminal, the file is not shown in Nautilus.

But when I put `ls` command, I can see the files on Terminal. But I cannot see them on Nautilus. What is the problem?

For example: `gnuplot plot` command creates a file name "End to End delay.png" and you can see that on terminal but that is not in nautilus.

I cannot see the newFile in nautilus but I can see that on terminal with `ls` command.

[image]

Thanks to Oli's command, The output of `stat "End to End delay.png"` is :

```
 File: ‘End to End delay.png’
  Size: 12839       Blocks: 32         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 806h/2054d  Inode: 20185175    Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/    reza)   Gid: ( 1000/    reza)
Access: 2015-01-27 15:51:14.912335621 +0330
Modify: 2015-01-27 16:17:35.752336388 +0330
Change: 2015-01-27 16:17:35.752336388 +0330
 Birth: -
```

Comment: It sounds suspiciously like you're looking in the wrong place. A couple of screenshots wouldn't hurt to confirm.

Comment: @oli I edited I add the screen shot

Comment: @KasiyA I edited and I add the screenshot. no directory is not hidden

Comment: So `End to End delay.png` is missing? Could you add the output of  of `stat "End to End delay.png"` to the question please? And press F5 in Nautilus to make sure it's not just a refresh issue.

Comment: @KasiyA oh I did not notice that :) . but I zoom my last picture that is a very small ">" not "." thank you very much for paying attention to my question.

Comment: :P my test path was short :P yes you are right. I removed old comments :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes Nautilus lags behind on filesystem changes. I don't think I've ever experienced a delay that allowed me to post a whole question but oh well.

You can refresh Nautilus by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>, or changing directory and then back.