# file is visible on my desktop but not via the ls command

Tags: filemanager

I have some Java programs that write some files to the desktop, read them, check them, and delete them. This might happen to about 50 files. Sometimes a few files remain on the desktop. The ones that remain seem random. I used to try to delete them but I resented doing that. I don't remember if deleting actually works but today I find that I can't delete the file. I discovered that after rebooting the files are gone.

Why is this happening?

There is a padlock icon on top of the icon of the file itself. The same program invocation can also result in *no* padlock icon on top of the file icon. If I right click the file icon in order to "move to trash" there is a dialog that says

> “Test Range.txt” can't be put in the trash. Do you want to delete it immediately?

If I choose to delete it immediately it says

> Error while deleting. Error when getting information for file '/home/jack/Desktop/Test Range.txt': No such file or directory

If I do `ls -la` the file is not present even though it is visible on the desktop.

I'm using Java 8 update 112 but I think this problem has been around since earlier versions of Java. I'm also using Ubuntu 16.04.

Addendum: In response to a request for more information I was asked to issue the command:

```
apt-cache policy nautilus nautilus-data
```

That command results in:

```
    nautilus:
  Installed: 1:3.18.4.is.3.14.3-0ubuntu5
  Candidate: 1:3.18.4.is.3.14.3-0ubuntu5
  Version table:
 *** 1:3.18.4.is.3.14.3-0ubuntu5 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:3.18.4.is.3.14.3-0ubuntu4 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
nautilus-data:
  Installed: 1:3.18.4.is.3.14.3-0ubuntu5
  Candidate: 1:3.18.4.is.3.14.3-0ubuntu5
  Version table:
 *** 1:3.18.4.is.3.14.3-0ubuntu5 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:3.18.4.is.3.14.3-0ubuntu4 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
```

Comment: It seems something related to `nautilus` (file-manage) . Could you add the output of `apt-cache policy nautilus nautilus-data` .  You can also force to update desktop by restarting it, `sudo killall nautilus; nautilus -n & disown`

Comment: Try reseting its settings `dconf reset -f /org/gnome/nautilus/` then `sudo killall nautilus; nautilus -n & disown`

Comment: It seems that your Java program is successfully deleting the files. It appears that the GUI is not loading that the file is gone. If you get the error saying "No such file or directory" and using `ls -la` doesn't show anything, your files are already gone. I would try asking (or editing your question) a question involving the GUI. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of a reboot, you can refresh the Desktop by pressing `F5` to get rid of the phantom icons.

[It is documented here in this askubuntu.com answer. I could not find a more canonical reference.](https://askubuntu.com/a/578363/25031)

Answer (score 3):

A reboot or a logout is not necessary.

In `terminal` type `nautilus -q`. Then quit terminal. Then click the `Files` icon in the launcher to bring back Nautilus... and your mysterious desktop icons should be gone.

Comment: This sort of works but I had to hold down the soft power button (on this Dell server) for about 1 second to revive the computer. Otherwise it appears to be an infinite loop.

Comment: Do you have ubuntu-desktop installed on this server? I didn't notice that you said this was a server before. How do you have a "desktop"? Can you put your work files in /tmp instead of the "desktop"?

Comment: I installed the regular desktop version of Ubuntu on this server. The reason I put files in ~/Desktop instead of /tmp is because I need convenient visibility.

Comment: I'd try this another time and see if you get the same result.

Answer (score 3):

This problem is not related to Java. Instead, it can probably be blamed on desktop caching. Namely, the files themselves were actually deleted, but the file manager (for whatever reason) did not respond to the fact that the files vanished, and keeps your "ghost" icon around.

You can fix this by killing Nautilus through `killall nautilus`, which will end all active Nautilus processes (including the desktop), clearing Nautilus' caches. Then, simply run Nautilus again from the menu or Dash, and your desktop would be reset. Sometimes, just hitting the <kbd>F5</kbd> key while on your desktop can also refresh and clear any icon caches.

Alternatively, you can reboot or relog your graphical session.

Comment: `nautilus --quit` would be better than `killall nautilus`. :-]

Comment: @DavidFoerster It would be, but you need to show that process who the boss is!

Comment: Haha, in that case it should be `killall -s KILL nautilus`. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

A reboot is not necessary. To quickly get rid of the deleted file icons that are still visible on your desktop, logout and then login again.

Comment: A GUI logout and GUI login works to get rid of the desktop icon remnants  but it has the side effect of closing open applications like Firefox and the Terminal. I no longer remember how to do non-`ssh` CLI logout and CLI login.